# Node js - How access another function in same controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two functions and i can't access from function 2 to function 1.
How can i do that?

```
class firstController
{        
  one(req, res)
  {
     var stamp = request.query("Select 'ALB'+left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5)+ left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5) as stamp");
     Promise.all([stamp]).then(function(listOfResults)
     {
      var data = listOfResults[0][0].stamp;
      res.send(data);
     }).catch(function(err)
     {
       // ... query error checks
       console.log(err);
     });
  }
  two(req, res){
    //get the data returned from function 1
    console.log(this.one(req, res));
  }
}
module.exports = firstController;
```

i have this error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getStamp' of undefined
```

Thank you

Comment: Its a bit hard to understand what you want to accomplish here. Promise is an async call so if you want to return the result of the promise, you have to add return before Promise.all

Comment: i want to get the value returned from function 1 in function 2. @R.Gulbrandsen

Comment: fn 1 does not return anything. res.send(data) will return data to the client but does not return data to another function

Answer (score 4):

Use **this** to access functions within the same class in ES6. This is quite complex in ES5 and ES6 compared to other languages and I recommend you have a look at it.

```
class firstController
{        
  one(req, res)
  {
    res.send("hello");
  }

  two(req, res){
     this.one(req, res);
  }
}
module.exports = firstController;
```

**UPDATE**
To get the data from one into two you'll need to return the result of the Promise like this

```
one(req, res) {
   var stamp = request.query("Select 'ALB'+left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5)+    left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5) as stamp");
   return Promise.all([stamp]).then(function(listOfResults) {
     return listOfResults[0][0].stamp;
   }).catch(function(err) {
     // ... query error checks
     console.log(err);
     return err;
   });
}

two(req, res){
  //get the data returned from function 1
  console.log(this.one(req, res));
}
```

Only use res.send when you want to return data to the client

Comment: change `this.one(req, send)`  => `this.one(req, res)`

Comment: i updated the function 1. I have an error to return data @ricky

Comment: when i instantiate the class, it says that "class is not a constructor"